# Is there a way to neutralize or override coconut flavour in a vegan dish?

Tags: flavor, vegan, coconut, cheesecake

I made a simple vegan cheesecake: coconut fat from coconut milk blended with pre-soaked raw cashews. Turned out real nice but the only thing is a strong coconut flavour.

Is there a way to neutralize it somehow?

Comment: A lot of times if I make something with an unexpectedly strong flavor that I'm not a huge fan of, I just try to complement it to make it more palatable. If you like everything about it except the too-strong flavor, I think it would be better to come up with a moderating sidekick than actually change the cake. Maybe a choco-coconut ganache with chopped cashews and caramel shards? Or maybe some pandan-flavored syrup? Also, recipe please? I'm not a vegan, but cashew/coconut cheesecake sounds magical to me. :)

Answer (score 3):

Definitely not if you're getting the fat from coconut milk. Using refined coconut oil would definitely help, but getting it to blend and stay emulsified might be a challenge. Lecithin from a soy product might keep things together– I use it in place of egg to make vegan mayonnaise. All of that saturated fat is pretty tough to emulsify though. Maybe a combination of your coconut milk fat and refined coconut oil? Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You can neutralize the coconut flavor using a very small amount of baking soda.  It works as a base to neutralize the lauric acid in the coconut, which is the "soapy" flavor mentioned in the first link below.

I tried it out and found it neutralizes the whole coconut flavor very nicely, but I recommend adding it to your recipe a very small amount at a time (1/4 teaspoon or less if possible) because if you add too much, the taste of baking soda becomes very prevalent.

Interesting reads for further details [here](http://www.cookingforengineers.com/forums/viewtopic.php?p=11621) and [here](https://food-hacks.wonderhowto.com/how-to/ingredients-101-use-baking-soda-neutralize-bitter-sour-flavors-food-0156750/)

Comment: At the same time, adding back acidity afterwards might be key (lime) :)